# Looking for an electronic copy of Holmgren's old paper

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, uniqueness-theorems

I would like to know if anyone has an electronic copy of the following paper:

> **"Holmgren, E.: Über Systeme von linearen partiellen Differentialgleichungen. Översigt Vetensk. Akad. Handlingar 58, 91–105 (1901)"**

In my search, the best result I found was the (possible) statement of the main result of this article which can be found in the following article: [https://people.kth.se/~haakanh/publications/Hed-MZ2.pdf](https://people.kth.se/%7Ehaakanh/publications/Hed-MZ2.pdf). More precisely,

**Theorem (Holmgren)** Suppose $I$ is a real-analytic nontrivial arc of $\partial \Omega$. Then if $u$ is smooth on a planar neighbohood $\mathcal{O}$ of $I$ and $\Delta^N u=0$ holds on $\mathcal{O} \cap \Omega$ with $\partial_{n}^{j-1}|_I=0$ for $j=1, \dots, 2N$, then $u(z)=0$ on $\mathcal{O} \cap \Omega$, provided that the open set $\mathcal{O} \cap \Omega$ is connected.

Any information is welcome, for example, if this article is published in a book.

Comment: The article has a [zbMath](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A32.0357.02) entry, with a short abstract. [This](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.5802/aif.1371.pdf) article by Hörmander also gives an overview. As a curious coincidence my grandfather Benny Brodda (who studied for some time under Hörmander) gave an extension to this theorem (using a generalisation due to F. John), see [this article](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10622/8643). I have not been able to find a copy of Holmgren's article yet.

Comment: In the meantime, in Hörmander's book "Linear partial differential operators" (1963), Chapter V, §5.3 (page 123), you'll find a full proof of Holmgren's theorem. It is formulated differently from your reference, but the content of the theorem is the same. I can post this formulation as an answer, if you wish.

Comment: Thank you! I know this version of Holmgren's Theorem, as in Hörmander's book. I was looking for the original article more out of curiosity, I didn't even find Holmgren's profile on MathSciNet, just some papers published in the Mathematische Annalen.

Comment: Also, I found a list of his publications: http://archive.ymsc.tsinghua.edu.cn/pacm_download/117/5645-11511_2006_Article_BF02547154.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The full text of the article can be found scanned [here](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/page/32299061#page/103/mode/1up).

Comment: Wow!  I didn't expect someone to find it so quickly, I've been looking for a week!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: We Swedes know where to find each other :-)